# How to use PDF.js to load file included in web app (not from "file:" URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, pdf.js

I want to be able to show PDF files within my Chrome app using [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) but the documentation is non-existent. I've been unable to find any simple examples or tutorials that show the code to load a PDF from a relative URL, show the page, and navigate through the PDF. They have very complex examples where 95% of the code does other things and it's very difficult to parse these and find the relevant functions. I would like to:

1. Include the relevant code in my app (is this the "pdf.js" created by "node make generic" and nothing else? Or do i need to include other JS files as well?)
2. Be able to show PDF files that are inside my `myapp.crx` file
3. Does pdf.js require "LocalStorage"? Will localStorage continue to be allowed in Chrome extensions/apps or is it deprecated?

Can someone tell me if #2 is possible and how to find some example code or documentation on the proper classes/functions to call and files to include/build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `node make generic` outputs to the `build/generic` directory. This directory contains two subdirectories, "build" and "web".
   "build" contains "pdf.js", which is the actual PDF engine.
   "web" contains a viewer, similar to the one at http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html.
2. After copying both of those previous directories to your app, you should be able to load the PDF file using `chrome.extensi/web/viewer.html?file=path%2Fto%3Ffile.pdf`
3. PDF.js does not require `localStorage`.It's used if available for persisting settings such as scroll position, but if unavailable, PDF.just continues to work without it.

There is one significant issue though: PDF.js loads the localization files using synchronous XMLHttpRequest. This is [not allowed](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated.html) in a Chrome app. You could solve this issue by serializing all files in the `locales`, put it in a single JavaScript file, load this in viewer.html, and simplify `l10n.js` to read the translations from the file I just described.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you say a bit more about what you mean with serializing all the files in `locales`? From what I can see, there is no `locales` folder. There is a `l10n` folder, is that what you mean? Also, if I want to make my own custom viewer and not use the `viewer.html`, do I still need to worry about that? Is the localization used by `pdf.js` or by `viewer.js`?

Comment: @DonRhummy There's a "locale" directory in `build/generic/`. If you want to use your own viewer, only `pdf.js` is needed. You can throw away all "web" things..

Comment: I saw your coment to @SergeyShevchenko and wanted to double check: when I pass the url to `PDFDocument` (or whatever class I need to instantiate), I pass it like `path/to/file.pdf` not `path%2fto%2ffile.pdf`, correct?

Comment: @DonRhummy Yes. Url-encoding is only needed if you pass the parameters via the query string. The relevant source for the parameter parsing is found [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/c682c25bcfd33405678af500a164f0b8be36f66a/web/viewer.js#L1292-L1303) (as you can see, it's specific to viewer.js; you said that you were using a homebrew viewer, so this comment is not relevant to you.).

Comment: Sorry to bring up an old question, but I want to double-check, will it be able to load files within a `.crx` that is a Chrome app and not a chrome extension? (Chrome apps do not have urls that can be put into the addressbar like an extension)

Comment: @DonRhummy You can get an absolute URL of a resource within your Chromium App with [`chrome.runtime.getURL`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime.html#method-getURL)

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify: normally you should be able to access a file baked into your CRX by providing a relative or absolute path to it within the CRX's internal directory structure, e.g.:

'myfiles/pdfs/example.pdf'

With PDF.js, I guess that's what "path-to-file.pdf" should be in Rob's answer above, verbatim.

Comment: `path%2Fto%2Ffile.pdf` is the URL-encoded version of `path/to/file.pdf`. It does not have to be a relative URL, it can also be absolute, as long as the page has the permission to access the URL.